# prove a operator is unitary.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space with the inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and norm $||\cdot||$.  Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $X$. 
 Prove if $X_0$ is a dense linear subspace of $X$ that $||T(a)||=||a||$ for  every element $a \in X_0$ and range $R(T)$ of $T$ is dense in $X$, then $T$ is unitary.

For me the dense set definition is every open set at least contain a point of dense set, I don't know what is relationship between dense set and unitary.  Hope to get proof of this question, thanks.

Comment: $X_0$ is dense means $\overline X_0=X$, where the overline denotes closure. A unitary operator is a bounded linear operator $U$ that satisfies $U^*U=UU^*=I$, where $U^*$ is the adjoint of $U$ and $I$ the identity operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unitary operator is simply an isometry which is surjective. Note that $T$ is a bounded operator, so the equation $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for  $x \in X_0$ extends to $X$. To show that $T$ is unitary it is enough to show that the range is closed (because a closed set which also dense is equal to the whole space). Let $Tx_n \to y$. Then $\|x_n-x_m\| =\|Tx_n-Tx_m\|\to 0$. By completeness of $X$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $x_n \to x$. But then $y=\lim Tx_n =Tx$ since $T$ is continuous. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a question. Is X0  not used in this proof?

Comment: @user724760 To show $T$ is an isometry, you have to use the fact that $X_0$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @user724760 I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, i understand.